# Best practice: What belongs in theme and what in plugin for large eCommerce website

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization

I am about to create a large custom eCommerce website that does not fit within WooCommerce. (Most of the times I use WooCommerce for eCommerce.) It has also a completely custom design.

However I know that WooCommerce is just a plugin. Rendering all templates when needed.

So my question is, how do you guys do this?

Maybe you just do the following:

- Put only the header, menu and footer code in your custom theme
- Render the rest of the theme templates via you plugin code

I am very curious if someone would argue that just all the code belongs in a gigantic theme with theme-partials.

Comment: Is your question how to include template files in a plugin and allow themes to overrie them? If so, you should change the title of the question, it is quite confusing.

Comment: Thank you, no I am just asking about best practice. It is a 'what do you do' question. I think myself I should do all code in the theme. I am curious what you do. How do you organise your code for a custom eCommerce website, completely written by yourself.